# How do I customize the zip file name when downloading multiple files?

Tags: files, contentversion, content, zip

I know how to download a single file from salesforce. I just open a new tab with the url `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/068xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/`.

Likewise, I know how to download multiple files into a zip. The url is
 `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/068xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/068yyyyyyyyyyyy`.

The catch with this one is, the zip file is always called `downloaded-content.zip`.

So what I want to know is, is it possible to give the zip file a custom name? For example, something like

`/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/068xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/068yyyyyyyyyyyy?zipAs=custom.zip`?

Comment: this URL string is a undocumented feature;

Comment: As rightly said by @cropredy its undocumented feature ie is a URL hack and can stop any moment. There's is an app on Appexchange, Mass File Download, its perfect solution to mass-download files/attachments related to a record or multiple records in just 1-2 clicks in a zip format with subfolders for each parent record. See if that meets your criteria. Check out app https://sforce.co/34thF8U